# Note under table incorrectly centered

Tags: booktabs

I have the following problem(s).
I have a sample table:

1. Unfortunately, the text under the table is also always centered and is not left-aligned. What can be done about this? And is there a way to make the text flush with the width of the table?
2. Strangely, the caption is also displayed below the table, although I actually wrote it above it. What can be the reason for this?
3. How to increase space between table and text globally?

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.75cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[nohyperlinks, printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\let\origfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\small}%
    \origfootnote{#1}%
    \endgroup}
    
    \begin{document}
        \FloatBarrier
        \begin{table}[h]
            \centering
            \caption{Parameter values used.}
            \label{tab:para}
            \begin{tabular}{@{}lcccc@{}}
                \toprule
                $\epsilon\in \left[ 0,0.5 \right]$ & $M=2$ & $\omega_1=1$ & $\omega_2=1$ & $\omega_3=1$ \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \\\footnotesize \emph{Note:} \lipsum[2]
        \end{table}
        \FloatBarrier
    \end{document}
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend/combine your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @dexteritas See my update

Comment: You seem to be asking two [or more] unrelated questions, here. On TeX.SX, we try to keep unrelated questions on separate pages. If you have multiple questions that are unrelated to one another, you should ask each in a separate TeX.SX "question". You'll stand a better chance of getting a satisfactory answer to each of your questions.

Comment: Just out of idle curiosity: What are you trying to achieve by writing `$\epsilon\in \left[ 0,0.5 \right]$`? Why not just write `$\epsilon\in[ 0,0.5]$`? and reduce the code clutter?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you enclose the `\centering` command and the `tabular` environment in a TeX group of their own. And if you don't want LaTeX to move the caption to the bottom automatically, don't load the `float` package.

> And is there a way to make the text flush with the width of the table?

You could load the `threeparttable` package and enclose the `\caption` directive, the `tabular` environment, and the subsequent legend in a `threeparttable` environment. However, in view of the facts that the table isn't wide and the legend is quite long, I wouldn't recommend taking this approach for the table at hand.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.75cm]{geometry} 
%% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % that's the default nowadays
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[nohyperlinks, printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
%\usepackage{amsfonts} 'amsfonts' is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
\usepackage{amssymb}

%%\usepackage{float}
%%\restylefloat{table}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

%\let\origfootnote\footnote
%\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{%
%    \begingroup
%    \renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\small}%
%    \origfootnote{#1}%
%    \endgroup}
    
    \begin{document}
    %\FloatBarrier
    
        \begin{table}[h]
        \caption{Parameter values used.\strut}
        \label{tab:para}

        \begingroup % limit scope of instr. to the curren TeX group
        \centering
            \begin{tabular}{@{}lcccc@{}}
            \toprule
            $\epsilon\in[0,0.5]$ & $M=2$ & $\omega_1=1$ & $\omega_2=1$ & $\omega_3=1$ \\
            \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \par
        \endgroup
            
        \medskip
        \footnotesize \emph{Note:} \lipsum[2][1-8]
        \end{table}
        
    %\FloatBarrier
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Adaptations

1. 1. Use `\raggedright` before your note OR
   2. Put the note inside the tabular with `\multicolumn{<number of columns}{l}{text}`, so it uses the width of the table.
2. Remove `\restylefloat{table}`

- I commented out `\renewcommand` of commands that weren't defined before.

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.75cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[nohyperlinks, printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{float}
%\restylefloat{table}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
%\renewcommand{\footnotelayout}{\setstretch{1}}
%\renewcommand{\footnotemargin}{1em}

\let\origfootnote\footnote
\renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\small}%
    \origfootnote{#1}%
    \endgroup}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Parameter values used.}
    \label{tab:para}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}lcccc@{}}
            \toprule
            $\epsilon\in \left[ 0,0.5 \right]$ & $M=2$ & $\omega_1=1$ & $\omega_2=1$ & $\omega_3=1$ \\
            \bottomrule
            \multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \emph{Note: \dots}}
        \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```